# Mutually Exclusive Comboboxes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

So, I've got 4 Comboboxes.  They all share the same list of options, lets say Apple, Banana, Carrot, Dill.

However, once the user selects one, that selection should not be available in the other comboboxes.  E.g. if they pick Apple in Combobox1, then the only selections available in Combobox2, 3, and 4 should be Banana, Carrot, and Dill.

Is there a good way to do this?  I originally thought to link the boxes datasource to a list containing the options, but they need separate datasources for separate choices.

Radio and checkboxes aren't really an option in the actual program, as the list of options is much larger than 4.  A Combobox seems to be the best way to represent the user's available choices here.

Comment: You say _they all share the same list of options_ and _they need separate datasources for separate choices_. So they have separate but same choices? Do you mean there could be some of same choices in multiple comboboxes, but they're not necessarily the same complete list of choices?

Comment: you could modify the datasource after each selection.  or present the user with one list and let them pick the order

Comment: @ChaseRocker The boxes just need to make sure there is never the same item selected in different comboboxes (exclusivity). I.E. ComboBox1 is set to "Apple" and ComboBox2 is set to "Apple".  This would be bad.  So I figured the best way to do that was to use a common running list of available items among all comboboxes, and have that list change every time the user selects an item in a box.

Comment: @Plutonix If they all have the same datasource, then making a selection on one box changes all other boxes to that same selection.  If i set box 1 to Apple, then boxes 2, 3, and 4 suddenly switch to Apple as well.

Comment: There hasn't been any activity on this post for a couple weeks. Please let us know how you solved this problem or if you require further help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to do what you are asking. This code assumes that the datasource uses an integer value to keep track of the items. If you are using the string value itself {Apple, Banana, etc.} as the id, the code will need to be amended slightly. If you need further help let me know but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

You can test this by creating a new blank form (Form1) and drop 4 combo boxes onto it (ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3, ComboBox4). Copy/paste this code over top of the form code and run to see how it works:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oComboBoxArray(3) As ComboBox
    Dim bPreventSelectedChange As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Set up an array with the combo box references to reduce code size by using loops later

        oComboBoxArray(0) = Me.ComboBox1
        oComboBoxArray(1) = Me.ComboBox2
        oComboBoxArray(2) = Me.ComboBox3
        oComboBoxArray(3) = Me.ComboBox4

        ' Populate all four combo boxes with the same datasource to start

        For Each oCbo In oComboBoxArray
            PopulateDataSource(oCbo)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateDataSource(oCombo As ComboBox, Optional nIdToSelect As Integer = 0)
        bPreventSelectedChange = True   ' Prevent code in ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged from executing while we change the datasource

        ' Using manually populated datatable as datasource because it's quick and easy to use

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

        ' Need to have some kind of "Please select an item:" in the list or else we will be unable to clear an already selected combo box

        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr("ID") = 0
        dr("Name") = "Select..."
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        ' If you are populating from a database or other dynamic source you will only have one of these 'if' statements within a loop

        If CheckSkipItem(oCombo, 1) = False Then
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr("ID") = 1
            dr("Name") = "Apple"
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If

        If CheckSkipItem(oCombo, 2) = False Then
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr("ID") = 2
            dr("Name") = "Banana"
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If

        If CheckSkipItem(oCombo, 3) = False Then
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr("ID") = 3
            dr("Name") = "Carrot"
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If

        If CheckSkipItem(oCombo, 4) = False Then
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr("ID") = 4
            dr("Name") = "Dill"
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If

        oCombo.DataSource = dt
        oCombo.DisplayMember = "Name"
        oCombo.ValueMember = "ID"
        oCombo.SelectedValue = nIdToSelect  ' Set value to either a) the "Select..." item or b) the item that was selected previously depending on the situation

        bPreventSelectedChange = False   ' Allow code in ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged to be executed by user again
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckSkipItem(oCombo As ComboBox, nID As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim bSkip As Boolean = False

        ' Loop through all combo boxes and see if this id has already been chosen in another combo box

        For Each oCbo In oComboBoxArray
            If oCbo IsNot oCombo AndAlso oCbo.SelectedValue = nID Then
                ' It has been chosen already so it is not valid for the current combo box that we are checking

                bSkip = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return bSkip
    End Function

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' Jump out of this event if the bPreventSelectedChange boolean is set to true (ie. if the combo box is being repopulated)

        If bPreventSelectedChange = False Then
            ' A value was chosen by the user. Reset all other combo box datasources and remove the recently selected value

            For Each oCbo As ComboBox In oComboBoxArray
                If sender IsNot oCbo Then
                    PopulateDataSource(oCbo, If(oCbo.SelectedValue = Nothing, 0, oCbo.SelectedValue))
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```